# When button clicked the app was Force Close

Tags: java, android, android-activity, random

I had make every activity Random if a button clicked but it seemsly not working good, the game was force close. "I Was using Bluestack as the emulato"

this is the following code

```
public class menu extends Activity {


    int time = 5, one, two, three, four, five, number;
    RelativeLayout layout1, layout2;
    Button button1; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
        editor.putInt("Lifes", 6);
        editor.putInt("Level", 0);  
        editor.putInt("One", 1);  
        editor.putInt("Two", 1);  
        editor.putInt("Three", 1);  
        editor.putInt("Four", 1); 
        editor.putInt("Five", 1);  


        editor.commit();


        layout1 =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        layout2 =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);


          new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

          @Override
          public void onFinish() {        
              layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }

          @Override
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          }
         }.start();  


        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.introbutton1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v){            
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
            editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
            editor.commit();


         // Here, we are generating a random number
         Random generator = new Random();
         number = generator.nextInt(5) + 1; 
         // The '5' is the number of activities

         Class activity = null;

         // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
         switch(number) { 
         // E.g., if the output is 1, the activity we will open is ActivityOne.class


             case 1: if(one == 1){
                 activity = activityone.class;
                 }

// if the activity was aready opened he will put value == 2, so the code will random again find activity with value == 1
                else if(one == 2){
                    Random generatorone = new Random();
                    number = generatorone.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                }

                 break;
             case 2: if(two== 1){
                 activity = activitytwo.class;
                 }
                else if(two== 2){
                    Random generatortwo = new Random();
                    number = generatortwo.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                }
                 break;
             case 3:if(three== 1){
                 activity = activitythree.class;
                 }
                else if(three== 2){
                    Random generatorthree = new Random();
                    number = generatorthree.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                }
                 break;
             case 4:if(four == 1){
                 activity = activityfour.class;
                 }
                else if(four == 2){
                    Random generatorFour = new Random();
                    number = generatorFour.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                }               

                 editor = pref.edit();
                 // Key,Value
                 editor.putInt("Activity", number);

                 editor.commit();      
                 }
         // We use intents to start activities
         Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
         startActivity(intent);
            }
         });
     }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

but when i click the button, the app was force close. Did i missing something? anyone can help?

in each activity there is a code to updated the value ==2

```
          public void onClick(View v){
                                        level++;
                                        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
                                        editor.putInt("Lifes", gamelifes);
                                        editor.putInt("Level", level);  
                                        editor.putInt("One", 2);
                                        editor.commit();
                                     // Here, we are generating a random number
                                        Random generator = new Random();
                                        number = generator.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                                        // The '5' is the number of activities

                                        Class activity = null;

                                        // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
                                        switch(number) { 
                                        // E.g., if the output is 1, the activity we will open is ActivityOne.class


                                            case 1: if(one == 1){
                                                activity = activityone.class;
                                                }
                                               else if(one == 2){
                                                   Random generatorone = new Random();
                                                   number = generatorone.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                                               }
                                                break;
                                            case 2: if(two== 1){
                                                activity = activitytwo.class;
                                                }
                                               else if(two== 2){
                                                   Random generatortwo = new Random();
                                                   number = generatortwo.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                                               }
                                                break;
                                            case 3:if(three== 1){
                                                activity = activitythree.class;
                                                }
                                               else if(three== 2){
                                                   Random generatorthree = new Random();
                                                   number = generatorthree.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                                               }
                                                break;
                                            case 4:if(four == 1){
                                                activity = activityfour.class;
                                                }
                                               else if(four == 2){
                                                   Random generatorFour = new Random();
                                                   number = generatorFour.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                                               }    
                                            default:if(level == 5){
                                                activity = activityfive.class;
                                                }

                                                editor = pref.edit();
                                                // Key,Value
                                                editor.putInt("Activity", number);

                                                editor.commit();      
                                                }
                                       // We use intents to start activities
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                 }                
         });
}
```

Comment: Include the error log in your question.

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: Brother, can you post your stacktrace also because it is difficult to find the bug without it

Comment: I think there is a `break;` statement missing from your code, right after `case 4` and before the `editor`. It might be the source of the error.

Comment: eh sorry guy's, i forget to note that i using bluestack so there is no error log lol

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the values to one, two ..and every time those values will be zero.So if always get the activity as null..So you need to assign the values to the variables one, two etc....

```
switch(number) { 
         // E.g., if the output is 1, the activity we will open is ActivityOne.class


             case 1: if(one == 1){
                 activity = activityone.class;
                 }

// if the activity was aready opened he will put value == 2, so the code will random again find activity with value == 1
                else if(one == 2){
                    Random generatorone = new Random();
                    number = generatorone.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                }
```

In the above code you are assigning the activity object. I think it is the problem once check!

Comment: the value will be updated to ==2 if one of activity completed, see my update question

Comment: But at first it will be zero right? So you dont get any activity object

Comment: hmmm, ok i will test changed the value

Answer (score 0):

You are calling sharedpreference twice with same variable name. This may be the issue.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

try to remove the one from button click and then check.

Comment: if i remove one of the sharedpreferences the code would be error